# Ubuntu - change keyboard layout in recovery mode terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

everyone. I've tried alt+shift, alt+ctrl, super+space, right ctrl+alt, shift+capslock and many many more, but none of them have worked. Is there any possibility to change layout? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you need to do in Recovery Mode?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe?

Comment: thank you for help, it was easier to reinstall ubuntu